# mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. What gives?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/php-error-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

I am trying to insert data from submitted form into database. The data is being successfully inserted into the DB but I keep getting this error message:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

And here's the code:

```
function senddata () {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("user", $con);
        $sql="INSERT INTO Employment (CollegeMajor) VALUE('$_POST[collegemajor]')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }


    mysql_close($con);
    }
```

The error message is referring to this line:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Why all the downvotes on this question?  Get an upvote just to ease the abuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

This is expected behavior.  `INSERT` statements return a boolean value, true on success and false on failure.

However, you really should look at [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I just deleted the row variable and it's all good now.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the function [mysql_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to get the result of an INSERT operation.

Answer (score 0):

what sort of result are you expecting after inserting a row into mysql?

if you want to obtain `auto-increment-id` - run `mysql_insert_id($con)`.